# Fallback for Chrome Custom Tab for OAuth 2.0 flow Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, chrome-custom-tabs

We are creating a native Android SDK for OAuth 2.0 flow. For security reason, we don't want to use WebView as a fallback for Chrome Custom Tabs. I'm curious to know if it possible to have an Android device without Custom Tabs?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in Android Studio create a generic AVD and launch your app on that, due to absence of a browser that implements CCT, the link is opened in generic browser window.